# Accessing class attributes in base (parent) class method with possible overloading by derived (children) classes

Tags: python, class, parent-child, static-variables, static-classes

I am trying to create a function in a parent class that references which ever child class ends up calling it in order to get a static variable that is in the child class.

Here is my code.

```
class Element:
  attributes = []

  def attributes_to_string():
    # do some stuff
    return ' | '.join(__class__.attributes) # <== This is where I need to fix the code.

class Car(Element):
  attributes = ['door', 'window', 'engine']

class House(Element):
  attributes = ['door', 'window', 'lights', 'table']

class Computer(Element):
  attributes = ['screen', 'ram', 'video card', 'ssd']

print(Computer.attributes_to_string())

### screen | ram | video card | ssd
```

I know how I would do this if it were an instance of the class using `self.__class__`, but there is no `self` to reference in this case.

Comment: instance methods should have `self` as first argument

Comment: if they are static, there should be [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator

Comment: The function is static and doesn't need `self`.

Comment: and how do you want to get class field `attributes` from static method? it should be class method (decorated with [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod)) then

Comment: I've never used `staticmethod` decorators before. Let me check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[decorating](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-decorator) with [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) should work

```
class Element:
    attributes = []

    @classmethod
    def attributes_to_string(cls):
        # do some stuff
        return ' | '.join(cls.attributes)


class Car(Element):
    attributes = ['door', 'window', 'engine']


class House(Element):
    attributes = ['door', 'window', 'lights', 'table']


class Computer(Element):
    attributes = ['screen', 'ram', 'video card', 'ssd']


print(Computer.attributes_to_string())
```

gives us

```
screen | ram | video card | ssd
```